# Error message not firing on opportunitylineitem record page

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, custom-field, error-messages

I have a requirement to display error message on opportunitylineitem record detail page when a user tries to update status field of the record once the related opportunity is set to closed won.

Here is the logic that I have achieved so far:

```
public class OpportunityLineItemHelper {
    public static void updateLineStatus(List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItemsToUpdate, Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldOliMap) {
        Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(OpportunityLineItem oli : lineItemsToUpdate) {
            oppIds.add(oli.OpportunityId);
        }
        Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppIds]);
        for(OpportunityLineItem oli : lineItemsToUpdate) {
            if(oppMap.containsKey(oli.OpportunityId) && oppMap.get(oli.OpportunityId).StageName == 'Closed Won') {
                if(oli.Status__c != null && oli.Status__c != oldOliMap.get(oli.Id).Status__c) {
                    oli.Status__c.addError('Status cannot be updated on a Closed Won opportunity.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that even though when i tried to update the field, i am not seeing any error and the record is saving succesfully.

Can anyone please suggest any changes here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a trigger in this case, a validation rule is enough to lock the Opportunity Product:

```
ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.StageName, 'Closed Won') && ISCHANGED(Status__c)
```

This one will lock the opportunity line item only when its status changes while the Opportunity's Stage is Closed Won, then you could set the error message to be displayed on Status field.

Since the `StageName` isn't a restricted picklist, be sure that the value is exactly 'Closed Won' and not 'Closed/Won' or something else.